# Variation with respect to inverse metric in a Lagrangian density

Tags: evaluation, physics, tensors, inverse

I am trying to vary the following Lagrangian density
with respect to the inverse metric appearing in the equation, but I am having trouble with how to write the right code in Mathematica.
I have already derived the result by hand.
Any help is appreciated
Thank you!
This is the mathematica code that I am using :

`coord = {t, x, y, z} n = Length[coord] metric = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (a[t])^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, (a[t])^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, (a[t])^2}} inversemetric = Inverse[metric] christof := christof = Simplify[Table[(1/2)* Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] -  D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1 n}, {k, 1,n}]] riemann :=riemann =Simplify[Table[ D[christof[[i, j, l]], coord[[k]]] -  D[christof[[i, j, k]], coord[[l]]] + Sum[christof[[s, j, l]] christof[[i, k, s]] -christof[[s, j, k]] christof[[i, l, s]], {s, 1, n}], {i, 1,  n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]] riccitensor :=  riccitensor = Simplify[Table[Sum[riemann[[i, j, i, l]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]] ricciscalar =  Simplify[Sum[inversemetric[[i, j]] riccitensor[[i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]] lagrangiandensity2 = (a[t])^3 (Sum[Inverse[metric][[b, c]]*riccitensor[[b, c]], {b, 1, 4}, {c, 1, 4}]/2 - V[\[Phi][t]] -f[\[Phi][t]] (Sum[Inverse[metric][[b, c]]*riccitensor[[b, c]], {b, 1, 4}, {c, 1,4}])^2/6 -1/2 Sum[Inverse[metric][[b, c]] D[\[Phi][t],coord[[b]]] D[\[Phi][t], coord[[c]]], {b, 1, 4}, {c, 1, 4}])`

Comment: Please provide some more detail in your problem and perhaps include your hand solution

Comment: I have added the full code , with all the calculations about the Riemann tensor,Ricci tensor and Ricci scalar .I hope that this might help ,thank you

Comment: I think that @MarcoB was referring to some explanatory background material so we can understand the context. If I understand correctly the necessities of the computation why not writing `metricnew = metric + ε pert` and expand in the small `ε` limit? It would automatically give you all the expressions as an expansion in powers of the small parameter. Then `Coefficient[expression,order of interest]` should yield the result. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Good morning , thank you for your effort.The lagrangian density is of the Einstein Gauss Bonnet theory and I am trying to use the VariatonalD command in Mathematica , to vary the lagrangian with respect to the inverse metric appearing in it.The problem is that every time I am doing so, I get this message  Part::pkspec1: The expression b cannot be used as a part specification.

Comment: when I vary the lagrangian with respect to the phi variable, using VariationalD, everything works perfect.

Comment: And this is the by hand result of the variation of the action\begin{align*}
    \delta S = \frac{1}{2} \int d^4 x \,\sqrt{-g} \delta g^{\mu\nu} (\,R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}\,R +\,g_{\mu\nu}\,V(\phi)\,
    -\frac{\theta_{\mu}\phi\,\theta_{\nu}\phi}{2}\,+g_{\mu\nu} (\,f(\phi) G_{GB})-\,\\
    \frac{2}{3} f(\phi) \,R\,R_{\mu\nu} +\,\frac{2}{3}\,\frac{\theta^2 (f \,R)}{\theta x^{\mu}\theta x^{\nu}}\,-\frac{2}{3}\,g_{\mu\nu} \,\Box (f\,R))\,=\,0

Comment: @liza it's useful to type @ and then the name of a user so we can receive a notification that you have replied in the comments. Also, as was mentioned earlier, the context should be in the main question and not in the comments. Furthermore, if you could give a general description of the task at hand it would be more helpful, otherwise it's like having an [`XY problem`](https://xyproblem.info/). Finally, what I suggested was to write the variation in a small parameter of the independent tensor structures in the beginning and then compute the Lagrangian density.

Comment: Hence, all the expressions would be written as `background` + `ε perturbation` + `ε^2 perturbation` + `...`

Comment: @liza thanks , I will keep that in mind.I thought that the by hand result could provide some help . For the moment I really do not have time for anything else.

Comment: @liza I don't think that this is a XY problem, I have already solved the task by hand and I have all the equations of motion.The thing is that I really want to present it in an nb.file as well, and the issue is how to write the right command so mathematica RECOGNIZES AND EXECUTES variation with respect to the metric based on the code of the lagrangian density